# Does this series converges fast enough to $e$ in order to guarantee this upper bound?

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Define the integral $I_n$ as
$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} e^xdx = a_ne+b_n $$
where  $a_n$ and $b_n$ are integers. We can integrate $I_n$ by parts $n$ times
$$I_n = (-1)^n \int_0^1\frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^xdx\\
= (-1)^n \int_0^1\frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} e^xdx$$
thus given an upper bound for it
$$|I_n| \leq \int_0^1\frac{[\text{max}(x-x^2)]^n}{n!} e^xdx=\frac{e-1}{n!4^n}.$$

Therefore
$$ |I_n| = |a_ne+b_n| \leq \frac{e-1}{n!4^n}.$$
My question is: if we replace $a_ne+b_n$ for $a_nS_n+b_n$ where
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} $$
is the upper bound for $a_nS_n+b_n$ still is $(e-1)/n!4^n?$ If not, what is the new upper bound?

edit: If I remember right $e-S_n\leq\frac{1}{n!n}$

Comment: You can use triangle inequality and sum the error of $e-S_n$ with your error to get an upper bound.

Comment: @fGDu94 Do you care to elaborate please? Or turn this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $|a_n S_n + b_n|$ with $I_n = a_n e + b_n$.

Using $|a_n e +b_n |\leq \frac{e-1}{n! 4^n}$,

$|a_n S_n + b_n | \leq |a_n S_n - a_n e + a_n e + b_n| \leq  |a_n S_n - a_n e |+ |a_n e +  b_n| \leq \sup (a_n) \frac{1}{n!} + \frac{e-1}{n! 4^n}$.

Potentially more analysis to do on the estimation of $\sup (a_n)$